# Как сделать так, чтоб данный таймер если вывести на одной странице несколько раз, работал

Tags: javascript

В общем, суть такая. Мне нужно чтоб данный таймер работал при последующем выводе, т.е. 
Пример:
1.До обработки (таймер работает)
2.До обработки (таймер уже не работает)
P.S. "До обработки" это у меня выводятся операции пользователей. А вот сам код, который я взял с этого сайта.

```
let out = document.getElementById('timeleft');
let start = new Date(out.dataset.end);

let timer = () => {
  let diff = start.getTime() - Date.now();
  if (diff <= 0) return clearInterval(i); // Конец
  diff /= 1e3; // мс -> с
  out.innerText = [
    diff / 3600 % 24 |0, // hours
    diff / 60 % 60   |0, // minutes
    diff / 1 % 60    |0  // seconds
  ].map(d => d<10?'0'+d:d).join(':');
};

let i = setInterval(timer, 450);
timer();
<span id="timeleft">00:00:00</span>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/QeppKN вот два только как их сделать не синхронными не знаю

Comment: Мне и надо чтоб они были синхронными, но, второй таймер должен появляться только тогда, когда выводится последующая информация. Например в первом столбике таймер работает, но как только пользователь добавляет второй столбик, таймер с первого столбика работает, а во втором нет

Comment: это уже через setTimeout делается

Comment: Вот знать бы как)

Answer (score 1):

Тот, кто писал этот таймер... явно экономил электричество на нажатие кнопок!))

Подменил id на class...

```js
let time = document.querySelectorAll('.time');
let x = Date.now();

function runTimer() {
  let diff = Date.now() - x;
  diff /= 1000; // мс -> с
  let text = [
    diff / 3600 % 24 | 0, // hours
    diff / 60 % 60 | 0, // minutes
    diff / 1 % 60 | 0 // seconds
  ].map(d => d < 10 ? '0' + d : d).join(':');
 
  for( var i = 0; i < time.length; i++ ){
    time[i].textContent = text; // Добавляем одинаковое время во все блоки.
  }
}

let i = setInterval(runTimer, 1000);
runTimer();

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(){
  let nova = document.createElement('div');
  nova.className = 'time';
  document.body.appendChild( nova );
  
  //Таймер спокойно тикает себе... 
  //Единственное - надо переопределить time, чтобы он учитывал добавленный элемент.
  time = document.querySelectorAll('.time'); 
});
```

```css
.time {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #123;
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Добавить</button><br>
<div class="time"></div>
```

Но хорошо бы дописать кусок, чтобы оно начиная эдак с 10-20 элементов, вывело один таймер где-то в углу. А в самих блоках уже обновляло время раз в минуту (clearInterval - setInterval)